# TCPDF - CMYK images in PDF appear "mainly black" in Illustrator

Tags: php, jpeg, tcpdf, adobe-illustrator, cmyk

I have a problem when opening with Illustrator a PDF generated with TCPDF that embeds a CMYK image (jpg).

The PDF looks just fine when opening it on a web browser or with Acrobat Reader.

But when trying to open it with Illustrator : although, the file is under the expected CMYK color mode, the rendered colors are not correct at all and looks "mainly black".

Basically :

1. I create and export a simple CMYK JPG image with Illustrator ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs6MA.png))

NB : embedding the color profile or not doesn't change the result.

2. I create the PDF and insert the CMYK jpg image using TCPDF :

   $this->pdf->Image("image.jpg", $x, $y, $w, $h, '', '', '', false, $dpi);

The result looks nice on a web browser or in Acrobat Reader : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyauE.png)

3. But the render is completely wrong when opening the PDF with Illustrator : [image of bad render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QazEk.png)

I have tried the two ways suggested here :
https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/issues/192

But nothing is working.

I would like to open the PDF with Illustrator to be able to make some manual changes in some cases.

Has anyone a clue about this ?

Comment: Seems like an Illustrator issue from your observations.

Comment: perhaps see https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90041/why-is-illustrator-changing-my-cmyk-numbers